# Flash players, css shadow and CPU usage

Tags: cpu-usage, vimeo, shadow

What a strange thing i've just discovered...
if i've got inset box-shadow or border-radius on any outter div (even many levels higher) then player generates about 40% CPU usage. Even if shadow isn't over/under this player.
How to fix it? Without shadow and border-radius it's about 18% CPU

I've got on my site structure like this:

```
<div> 
   <div>
      <div>
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/15273408" width="700"
       height="400" frameborder="0"
       webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
box-shadow: inset 5px 7px 10px -5px black; border-radius: 3px;
```

I confirmed this behavior in both Firefox and Chrome; using a PNG background property doesn't exhibit this problem.

Comment: Which browsers? Which CSS settings specifically?

Comment: box-shadow: inset 5px 7px 10px -5px black; 
border-radius: 3px; 
Browsers: i've checked only firefox and chrome. This problem is even on vimeo.com (on some pages). I've fixed it by replacing css box-shadow by background property with .png... but now i've got this problem in another place, where I display this player like modal window (but in this situation all players with wmode="opaque" causes this problem, only wmode="window" fixes it, but vimeo doesn't allow to do this). I've noticed that if I move my modal player out of site (for example margin-top: -2000px) then it's ok. It can't be over